# Flutter StreamBuilder how i can run setState() when ConnectionState.done?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I am using `StreamBuilder` to display a loading progress bar. It is possible on reaching `ConnectionState.done` - run `setState()` for updating my widgets that are outside of `StreamBuilder`?.

If I try to call `setState()` from a widget, I get an error

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

```
 case ConnectionState.done:
          children = <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                        Icons.info,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                         size: 60,
                         ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                            child: Text('\$${snapshot.data} (closed)'),
                          )
                        ];
                        
                        //I'm trying to trigger an update
                        setState((){
                          isOffsetLoading = true;
                        });
                        
                        break;
```

Comment: It is always helpful if you could provide a readable and reproducible code and also the exact error that you are getting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From thhe docs:
Streambuilder: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

> Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Stream.

setState: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

The error means that you are calling setState while the widget is building which will cause the widget to rebuild repeatedly.

You can update `isOffsetLoading` and call setState in a separate function and call the function instead in your code in the question.

Comment: what is `isOffsetLoading?` I tried different options - async call `setState`, `setState` in a separate function also `ValueListenableBuilder` no success.

Comment: I don't know what `isOffsetLoading`is. Is that not what you are trying to update in the code you have posted in your question?

Comment: You can also consider using BehaviourSubject to update the value and call setState in the listen handler  https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, I read the documentation and I think my idea is impossible to implement....

Comment: As @joy-terence pointed out, if you provide  a  "readable and reproducible code" it will be easier to get assistance with that. 

The listen method of the BehaviorSubject takes a function and you can call setState in the function passed to the listen method.

Example of BehaviorSubject with setState in the listen method  can be found here:
https://www.filledstacks.com/snippet/use-rx-dart-in-flutter-to-synchronize-ui/